# What are the configurations that can be done such that Postgres loads faster in pgAdmin4?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-18.04, pgadmin-4

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 system and I just logged into the remote Postgres database using pgAdmin4. The loading of the database itself initially took sometime. Later on I tried to open/view the tables from the database from the schemas option within it. What then happened was it kept loading at least for another few minutes until one of the table opened displaying 'Data retrieving from database', and when I would like to check the other table the wait time remained the same. Can someone help me with the processing time as working with the tables is testing my patience? Is there any configuration required in pgAdmin or postgres required to be done that might help me work with the tables faster?

I could not find any configuration that could help me process the database faster.

Comment: Have you tried using any other tool? eg psql?

Answer (score 0):

It is a known fact that pgAdmin takes a long time to render large result sets. It is not a good tool for that purpose.

I'd recommend that you use `psql` for that.

Comment: Sure would try that